# Is to possible to delay the needle loading animation in Highcharts angular gauge?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, gauge

I have created a Highcharts Angular gauge. I need to delay the needle loading animation.

Here is the code:

```js
$(function () {

    $('#meter').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'gauge',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBackgroundImage: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },
      credits: {
          enabled: false
      },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
      //
      plotOptions: {
            gauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                dial: {
                    radius: '70%',
                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                    topWidth: 1,
                    baseWidth: 5,
                    rearLength: '20%'
                },
                pivot: {
                    radius: 5,
                    borderWidth: 5,
                    borderColor: '#000',
                    backgroundColor: '#fff'
                }
            }
        },

        pane: {
            startAngle:-90,
            endAngle: 90,
            center: ['50%', '55%'],
                size: '85%',
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,              
                background: {
                    backgroundColor: '#0187CC',
                    innerRadius: '110%',
                    outerRadius: '100%',
                    borderColor: 'transparent',
                    shape: 'arc',
                    
                },
        },

        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 30,
            
            minorTickInterval: 'auto',
            minorTickWidth: 0,            
            minorTickLength: 10,
            minorTickPosition: 'inside',
            minorTickColor: '#0187CC',            

            tickPixelInterval: 30,
            tickWidth: 10,
            tickPosition: 'inside',
            tickLength: 10,
            tickColor: '#0187CC',           
            labels: {
                step: 2,
                rotation: 'auto'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            plotBands: [{              
                color: '#FFF' 
            } 
          ]
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Speed',
            data: [20],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' Mbps'
            }
        }]

    },

    // Add some life
    function (chart) {
        if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
            setInterval(function () {
                var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                    newVal,
                    inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0) * 0);

                newVal = point.y + inc;
                if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
                    newVal = point.y - inc;
                }

                point.update(newVal);

            }, 3000);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.highcharts-title, .highcharts-button, .highcharts-data-labels, .highcharts-tooltip, .highcharts-axis path:last-child , .highcharts-axis path:first-child, .highcharts-axis path:nth-child(13){
 display: none;
}


.highcharts-axis-labels text{
 fill: #000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="meter.js"></script>


<div id="meter" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: do you want delay based on some condition or exactly why you need delay ?

Comment: You may add animation: { duration:2000} inside your series for changing the animation of your needle. Here you can find information about this parameter in Highcharts API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.gauge.animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 'plotOptions` attribute, add the following code:

```
series: {
    animation: {
        duration: 2000
    }
}
```

This will cause the gauge needle to start up more slowly. Increase the number to slow it down; decrease the number to speed it up.

See also the updated code snippet below.

I hope this is helpful!

```js
$(function () {

    $('#meter').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'gauge',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBackgroundImage: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },
      credits: {
          enabled: false
      },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
      //
      plotOptions: {
            gauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                dial: {
                    radius: '70%',
                    backgroundColor: '#000',
                    topWidth: 1,
                    baseWidth: 5,
                    rearLength: '20%'
                },
                pivot: {
                    radius: 5,
                    borderWidth: 5,
                    borderColor: '#000',
                    backgroundColor: '#fff'
                }
            },
            series: {
                animation: {
                    duration: 2000
                }
            }

        },

        pane: {
            startAngle:-90,
            endAngle: 90,
            center: ['50%', '55%'],
                size: '85%',
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,              
                background: {
                    backgroundColor: '#0187CC',
                    innerRadius: '110%',
                    outerRadius: '100%',
                    borderColor: 'transparent',
                    shape: 'arc',
                    
                },
        },

        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 30,
            
            minorTickInterval: 'auto',
            minorTickWidth: 0,            
            minorTickLength: 10,
            minorTickPosition: 'inside',
            minorTickColor: '#0187CC',            

            tickPixelInterval: 30,
            tickWidth: 10,
            tickPosition: 'inside',
            tickLength: 10,
            tickColor: '#0187CC',           
            labels: {
                step: 2,
                rotation: 'auto'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            plotBands: [{              
                color: '#FFF' 
            } 
          ]
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Speed',
            data: [20],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' Mbps'
            }
        }]

    },

    // Add some life
    function (chart) {
        if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
            setInterval(function () {
                var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                    newVal,
                    inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0) * 0);

                newVal = point.y + inc;
                if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
                    newVal = point.y - inc;
                }

                point.update(newVal);

            }, 3000);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.highcharts-title, .highcharts-button, .highcharts-data-labels, .highcharts-tooltip, .highcharts-axis path:last-child , .highcharts-axis path:first-child, .highcharts-axis path:nth-child(13){
 display: none;
}


.highcharts-axis-labels text{
 fill: #000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="meter.js"></script>


<div id="meter" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I meant was needle animation delay on start. I need to start the needle animation after full page load.

Comment: @SubinGeorge `$( document ).ready()` should take care of that if you use jQuery. What other items do you have loading on the page? Perhaps you could either: 1) place them first in the order of JS-related items that are loading, with the chart code at the bottom, or 2) set a delay on the chart code that's dependent on some other item being loaded first.